# Recurrence in arrow functions (JS Harmony)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, recurrence, arrow-functions

Recently, I have written this function for an OP:

```
$.prototype.reduce = function reduce(obj1, obj2) {
  for (var k in obj2) {
    if (obj1.hasOwnProperty(k) && obj2.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      if (typeof obj1[k] == "object" && typeof obj2[k] == "object") {
         reduce(obj1[k], obj2[k]);
      }
      else delete obj1[k];
    }
  }
}
```

This function uses the feature of *named functions expressions* to make use of recurrence. I am now wondering, how to accomplish the same behavior using the new arrow function, as they are *per definition* always anonymous.

```
$.prototype.reduce = (obj1, obj2) => {
  for (var k in obj2) {
    if (obj1.hasOwnProperty(k) && obj2.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      if (typeof obj1[k] == "object" && typeof obj2[k] == "object") {
         XXXX          }
      else delete obj1[k];
    }
  }
}
```

In place of `XXX`, I would have the following ideas:

**1.** `arguments.callee(obj1[k], obj2[k]);`(obviously deprecated)

**2.** `$.reduce(obj1[k], obj2[k])` (calling the function variable itself - will fail for self-invoking function expressions)

**3.** Keep using "classical" function expression

Are there more approaches I missed? Which is the best way to use recurrence in double arrow functions?

Comment: Yes, you should keep using normal function expressions, or use the variable that you assigned to. Another possibility would be the y-combinator as mentioned in the duplicate.